# VNC Server not autostarting on RPi3

Tags: server, vnc

http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-up-a-VNC-Server-on-your-Raspberry-Pi/step4/Setting-up-the-Pi-to-Automatically-Start-a-VNC-Ser/

I have seen various tutorials explaining the exact process in the link above but I can't for the life of me work out why I can't get it to work.

VNC server works great if I manually boot it up with `sudo vncserver`.

I have created the specified autostart folder and inside of it placed a file called vncserver.desktop.

Inside that file there is the following information:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=TightVNC
Exec=vncserver:1
StartupNotify=false
```

Can anyone help?

My Raspberry Pi has been updated to the latest version by using:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After updating, I tried to run RealVNC but it didn't work so I am not sure it was installed after doing the upgrade process?  Hence, I installed tightVNC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an easier solution.

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Problem solved. Using Microsoft Remote Desktop works perfectly on boot.

I imagine though that some people will say it is better to go with VNC but I am not sure why.

Comment: The primary advantage to VNC is that you get the desktop and don't need to worry about reconnecting to virtual sessions.  But that is easily fixed by going into /etc/xrdp and editing the xrdp.ini file so the first session says "ask5910" instead of -1  -  side effect is that for your first session you do need to manually change the 5910 to -1 upon login.  Afterwards it will default to 5910 so you will reconnect.

Comment: Please fix the answer - it should be `xrdp` and not `xrpd`

Answer (score 1):

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade
 apt-get dist-upgrade
```

after finish

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then go to Interfacing Options then select vnc and enable it and reboot
enjoy your vnc server running on boot

Comment: This works great.  Note that any other vnc servers will be removed at this step (like vnc4server) - but press on and it all works out OK.  Plus, the ~/.vnc/passwd file is not reset so you still have the same login password.  And with this answer it will now work with all clients - both Windows TightVNCviewer and Linux remmina.

Answer (score 1):

Dropped ":1" from the above and it worked the next time i booted ....

Comment: Why did this help solve the problem? Your answer may give a valid solution, but without further context it's not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with a headless Pi - used [this](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=230779) solution

> If you do not have a keyboard or mouse connected to your Pi, VNC Server may not start automatically.

Solving it with(install another entropy generator):

> sudo apt-get install haveged

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to disable Wayland if you happened to have it enabled. VNC does not work with Wayland.

More information here: https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/4417193011857-How-do-I-disable-Wayland-to-use-VNC-Connect-.